# How to correctly use Promise.all to combine two datasets and return a single object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, dictionary

I have an existing object `data`.
I am using NodeJS `async` function to retrieve value of `fetchResponse`.
Finally, I am trying to embed the `fetchResponse` to the existing `data` object using the following `for loop`

```
for (let key in data) {
    for (let number in data[key]) {
        data[key][number].map( async d=> {
            const fetchResponse = await sequelize
                .query(await fetchHostDetails(d.Hostname), options);
        data[key][number]['Fetchresult'] =  fetchResponse;
        });
    }
}
return data;
```

I see that `data` is still having the original value and not including the `key value pair` `Fetchresult : fetchResponse`

I am trying to use `Promise.All` as below but it is still giving original `data` object value.

```
for (let key in data) {
    for (let number in data[key]) {
        data[key][number].map( async d=> {
            const fetchResponse = await sequelize
                .query(await fetchHostDetails(d.Hostname), options);
             await Promise.all({...d, Fetchresult : fetchResponse});
        });
    }
}
return data;

const data =
{
  "error1": {
    "7": [
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
        "Hostname": "host123.com"
      }
    ],
    "8": [
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
        "Hostname": "host223.com"
      },
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-1C",
        "Hostname": "host1231.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am getting below `fetchResponse` for hostName under `Error-1A`

```
const fetchResponse =
    [
      {
        "resType": "unknow data",
        "res": "missing data"
      },
      {
        "resType": "login failed",
        "res": "login with wrong userid"
      }
    ]
```

Similarly there will be separate `fetchResponse` for hostName under `Error-1b` and `Error-1C` but response format will be similar to what we have got for `Error-1A`.

For `data.error1[8]` we are getting 2 values of `fetchResponse` but please note that those are 2 separate values for `Error-1B` and `Error-1C`. One will be displayed after `Error-1B` and other will be displayed after `Error-1C`.

Comment: `map` returns an array. If you are not using the returned array, you are using `map` incorrectly. In this case, you may be able to use [`for await .. of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) (without `Promise.all`) to help with what your doing, although what you're doing is quite unclear.

Comment: I have added more clarity to my question. Please have a look

Comment: For `data.error1[8]` you'll be getting multiple `fetchResponse`s (one for each hostname). What exactly do you want to do with that `fetchResponse`?

Comment: For `data.error1[8]` we are getting 2 values of `fetchResponse` but please note that those are 2 separate values for `Error-1B` and `Error-1C`. One will be displayed after `Error-1B` and other will be displayed after `Error-1C`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me to use `await` in a loop.  I'd prefer to generate a single, flat list of promises to eventually have one `Promise.all` that awaits them all.

Allow me to use a `placeholderAsyncOperation` to stand in for your fetch using the key and number.  For demonstration purposes, I'll just delay a bit and then returns some object based on the parameters.  I'll use your original input `data` though.

```js
const data =
{
  "error1": {
    "7": [
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
        "Hostnames": "host123.com,hostabc.com,host33a.com..."
      }
    ],
    "8": [
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
        "Hostnames": "host223.com,host2c.com,host43a.com..."
      },
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-1C",
        "Hostnames": "host1231.com,host2abc.com,host313a.com..."
      }
    ]
  },
  "error2": {
  },
  "error3": {
  }
}

async function placeholderAsyncOperation(key, number, result) {
  await delay(1000);
  return {key, number, resultJSON: JSON.stringify(result)};
}

const delay = time_ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time_ms));


let promises = [];
for (let key in data) {
  for (let number in data[key]) {
    promises.push(data[key][number].map(val => (placeholderAsyncOperation(key, number, val))));
  }
}

Promise.all(promises.flat()).then(result => console.table(result));
```

#### NOTE: About this snippet:

This uses `console.table` that Stack Overflow doesn't support so well yet (output embedded into the page will appear empty), so if you run this snippet in your browser you'll likely have to ***open your browser's built-in console before running the snippet***.  Like, by pressing F12 or however your browser shows its console.

Comment: i dont want to use `await delay(1000);` Also it is backend NodeJS code so won't be running it on browser

Comment: @meallhour As the name of the function says, this is just a `placeholderAsyncOperation` for demonstration purposes. Do your fetching and database stuff in there.

Answer (score 0):

I would first of all build an array containing all the promises, along with key and index:

```js
let promises = [];

for (let key in data) {
  for (let number in data[key]) {
      let p = async() => {
           const fetchResponse = await sequelize.query(
               await fetchHostDetails(d.Hostname), options
           );
           return {key, number, fetchResponse};
      };
      promises.push(p);
   }
}
```

Now, before you inject this "fetch" data into your original data, the promises need to resolve. So we use an async function:

```js
const merge = async (data, promises) => {
    
    // wait for all promises
    const resolvedPromises = await Promise.all(promises);

    // inject the results into "data"
    resolvedPromises.forEach(row => {
        if (row) {
            const {key, number, fetchResponse} = row;
            data[key][number]['Fetchresult'] =  fetchResponse;
        }
    });

    return data;

};
```

When you call this, remember it's async:

```js
merge(data, promises).then(newData => {

   console.log(newData);

});
```

Comment: I am getting an error `Error: undefined : TypeError: data.map is not a function`

Comment: I see. I assumed data[key] was an array. Try the updated code I just edited

Comment: In some cases `fetchResponse` is null, and I am getting an error - `TypeError: Cannot set property 'Fetchresult' of undefined` Can you also add null validation check for `fetchResponse`?

Comment: I have added this logic. does it look fine to you?        `resolvedPromises.forEach(row => {
                const {key, index, fetchResponse} = row;
                const fetchData = fetchResponse ==  null ? "No Notes Yet" : fetchResponse;
                data[key][index]['Fetchresult'] =  fetchData;
            });`

Comment: `Error: undefined : TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined`

Comment: sure. Try now. I added a `if (row) {}` check so that only truthy values are processed